# chars by unicode not appear on html

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I tried to get Unicode of the "" emoji with javascript but not appear when I try to add it as HTML, a lot of emojis not appear

```
var x="A".charCodeAt(0);
document.write(x); // gaves 65
```

`&#65;` gave A

```
var y="".charCodeAt(0);
document.write(y); // gaves 55358
```

`&#55358;` didn't give

What is the reason?

Comment: Not valid [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/55358/index.htm) nor [there](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/%26%2355358%3B)

Comment: `charCodeAt` returns a UTF-16 code unit, not a character (see documentation on MDN). Emojis are not on basic multilingual plan, so they requires two code units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Characters (or code points) in JavaScript are made up of code units. Sometimes, a code point is made up of one code unit. For example, the code point for "a" is made up of one code unit (97 or 0x61). Other code points however are made up of two code units (known as a surrogate pair) that work together to form a single character.  For example, the Thinking Face emoji () you shared in your question is made up of two code units which when paired together make the one code point to form the thinking face emoji. You can see this by taking the `.length` of it:

```js
console.log("".length); // 2 (as made up of two code points)
console.log("".charCodeAt(0)); // 55358 or 0xD83E
console.log("".charCodeAt(1)); // 56596 or 0xDD14
```

When you use [`.charCodeAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) you're accessing the *code units* of your string elements. As seen above, `""` comprises of two code units, 0xD83E (55358) and 0xDD14 (56596). The first code unit returned by `.charCodeAt(0)` only makes sense when used together with other code units, and so it doesn't work standalone, which is why you're getting the replacement character symbol (�) in your result:

```js
console.log(""[0], ""[1]); // � �
```

Rather than using the individual code units obtained by `.chartCodeAt()`, you can show the entire code point (ie: character), which can be obtained using [`.codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt):

```js
console.log("".codePointAt(0)); // 129300 or 0x1F914
```

Then, you can use this number as a HTML entity:

```html
<p>&#129300;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This emoji:  has a decimal (dec) reference of 129300. If you want it to show in your HTML try this:

```html
<p>&#129300;</p>
```

For a full list of dec references visit [w3schools' website](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji.asp).